# Backward differentiation formula vs. backward difference (finite difference)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

I'm studying numerical methods to solve differential equations, but I don't understand the differences between "Backward differentiation formula" and "backward difference" (finite difference).

For example what formula it was applied here for the time derivatives ?

$w_\tau(\tau_m,\xi_i) \approx
\begin{cases}
(w^m_i-w^{m-1}_i)/k, & m=1,\\
(\frac{3}{2}w^m_i-2w^{m-1}_i+\frac{1}{2}w^{m-2}_i)/k, & m\geq2,
\end{cases}$

Also, the acronym BDF stands for "backward differentiation formula" or for "backward finite difference" ?

Comment: The BDF formulas (backward differentiation formulas) are a type of numerical method called 'multistep methods', in that they use the solution values at previous times $y_{n-1}, y_{n-2}, \dots$ to compute the current solution $y_{n}$. Backward finite difference refers to numerical schemes that are implicit i.e those where finite differencing yields an algebraic equation of the form $$y_{n} = F(y_{n}, y_{n-1}, y_{n-2}, \dots)$$

Comment: thanks for the reply, in the equation I wrote in the question there is the term $w^m_i$ on right hand side, so did they apply backward finite difference ?

Comment: In order to determine whether they used forward (explicit) or backwards (implicit) finite differencing, they need to apply it to an ODE. Here, I can't determine which one they used because you haven't told me what the authors applied it to and what the result was. Why don't you write out exactly what it says in the book, before and after what you have written above, it will save us a lot of time. The numerical method you have written down is saying use one of the Euler methods for the first step, then use the BDF2 formula for the rest of the steps.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7oI6sP6.png They said "we use a backward difference formula of second order (BFD2)" but they wrote "difference" not "differentiation", so I don't understand what they actually used.

Comment: They meant differentiation. So what they have done is used a _backward Euler_ (which is just the BDF1 formula) on the time derivative for the _first_ timestep, so that they obtained the values $w^{0}$ and $w^{1}$. Then the authors used the BDF2 formula for the rest of the timesteps.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help and patience! I would upvote you if only I could

Comment: All good, as long as you understand now I'm happy.